# CodeIgniter 500 Internal Server Error on working site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

My site tourisminbhutan.com is build in Codeignitor & working fine but showing "500 Internal Server Error" in page header response code. Browser console &  https://httpstatus.io/ showing error.

Here is the HTTP response I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error =>
Date => Thu, 27 Apr 2017 07:07:26 GMT
Server => Apache
Expires => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma => no-cache
Set-Cookie => PHPSESSID=o2rlin6qh157pd141ivba31no0; path=/
Connection => close
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**I can't figure out where is problem. Please help.**

Comment: it works just fine now

Comment: Please check in https://httpstatus.io/

Comment: In which action you got 500 error -@SandeepKumar

Comment: Browser Console showing error "GET http://www.tourisminbhutan.com/ 500 (Internal Server Error)" @ubm

Comment: Check the error_log, it will tell why httpstatus.io gets a 500 and you don't (I don't either)

Answer (score 0):

This should be your initial check list in case of 500 HTTP error code:

- Check the validity of *.htaccess files and file permissions.
- Check for any programming syntax errors.
- Check server error logs for any hidden errors.
- Make sure that you have the minimum requirement needed to operate Codeigniter Framework especially PHP version.

Please update me. Thank you

Comment: Um, read the OP's question again. The website is fine, only httpstatus.io gets the error.